# Website traffic referral from cfauth.com

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, referrer

Google Analytics is reporting several referrals from a site called `cfauth.com`.

I can't seem to find any information on this site other than it's connection to a security firm. It's definitively not a site with a link to mine.

Does anyone know more about this?

Comment: Please share your URL for analyzing.

Answer (score 1):

Someone is probably surfing your site using their web-based proxy. They have proxy services that can cause referral traffic. Here is a [link to their proxy](http://www.bluecoat.com/products/proxysg) for more information.